# Parse Cloud Code: Logic Branching in Promises

Tags: javascript, parse-platform, parse-cloud-code

I'm trying to write a Parse.com Cloud Code function to accomplish the following workflow:

1. User submits a value.
2. Cloud code function checks to see if that value matches any objects of type `code`.
3. If not, the function returns a "not found" value.
4. If so, the object of type `code` is assumed to have a pointer to an object of type `item`.
5. Then, `code.item` is checked to see whether it has a pointer to an object of type `alert`.
6. If not, the function returns a "not found" value.
7. If `code.item.alert` **does** exist, then I want to fetch the full `alert` object, including pointers which may or may not exist, up to 2 layers deep.

As I begin writing the code for this function, I can get it working to the point of checking to see whether the `code` exists and, if so, whether `code.item.alert` also exists.

This is where the problem arises. As it currently stands, in the working version of my function, the `alert` item that is returned is only the class type and objectId. I understand why that is happening, and I am trying to write code to populate the object before returning it, but I am failing in that attempt.

Here's the code that is working so far (but only returning the `alert` object's shell):

```
Parse.Cloud.define("alertLookup", function (request, response) {
    Parse.Cloud.useMasterKey(); 

    var codeQuery       = new Parse.Query("code");  
    codeQuery.equalTo("value", request.params.code);
    codeQuery.include("item");

    codeQuery.find().then(function (codes) {
        if (codes.length === 0) {
            response.success("no item");
        } else {
            var code    = codes[0];
            var item    = code.get("item");
            var alert   = item.get("alert");
            if (alert === null || alert === undefined) {
                response.success("no item");
            } else {
                response.success(alert);
            }
        }       
    }, function (error) {
        response.error(error);
    });
});
```

Here's what I have tried that is failing with an error code of 141:

```
Parse.Cloud.define("alertLookup", function (request, response) {
    Parse.Cloud.useMasterKey(); 

    var codeQuery       = new Parse.Query("code");  
    codeQuery.equalTo("value", request.params.code);
    codeQuery.include("item");

    codeQuery.find().then(function (codes) {
        if (codes.length === 0) {
            response.success("no item");
        } else {
            var code    = codes[0];
            var item    = code.get("item");
            var alert   = item.get("alert");
            if (alert === null || alert === undefined) {
                response.success("no item");
            } else {
                return alert.fetch();                   
            }
        }       
    }).then(function (a) {
        response.success(a);

    }, function (error) {
        response.error(error);
    });
});
```

Why won't the `fetch()` call work properly? When I insert `console.log()` statements, although `alert` is non-null, `return alert.fetch();` does not ever seem to be called. At least, the `response.success(a);` line is never called. Why not?

Comment: what is the 141 error message you get ?

Comment: "undefined." That's it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead while chaining Promises:

```
codeQuery.find().then(function (codes) {
    if (codes.length != 0) {
        var code    = codes[0];
        var item    = code.get("item");
        var alert   = item.get("alert");
        if (alert != null && alert != undefined) {
            var alertObj = new Parse.Object("alert"); // alert class ???
            alertObj.id = alert.id;
            return alertObj.fetch();                   
        }
    }
    // return a Promise for no items
    return Parse.Promise.as("no item");

}).then(function (a) {
    response.success(a);

}, function (error) {
    response.error(error);
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but that yields the same results for me. And, as you can see, the error message I'm getting is worthless. Even the Parse Console Log/Error Log give me no information.

Comment: 141 error is usually a scripting error from JavaScript engine. I suspect your problem is calling `fetch` on the `alert` variable which potentially is not a Parse object. I made some changes in the code to make sure you are calling `fetch` on a Parse object that represents an `alert` object.

Comment: Same thing. I believe all of these methods should work, but I cannot figure out why they are not. I am getting it to somewhat work when breaking this up into 2 functions, but that seems very kludgy to me. Also, even in the 2nd method, it's breaking in odd and unexpected ways. I'm getting ever more frustrated with Parse.